# What is the MSSQL equivalent to the EXPLAIN (or DESCRIBE) keyword

Tags: mysql, sql-server, explain

In MySQL we can use EXPLAIN {query} and we can get a nice grip on the performance of the said query. I want to help a friend who works with MSSQL and I don't know what is the equivalent or if there is one for the EXPLAIN keyword. EXPLAIN is a synonym with DESCRIBE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449814/sql-server-equivelant-to-mysqls-explain

Comment: this question was answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan

Comment: MS Sql Server :equivalent of DESC is SP_HELP